# How do I get mediaelement.js player state (paused, volume, etc.)?

Tags: mediaelement.js

According to what is stated on [mediaelement.js website](http://mediaelementjs.com/#api) it should be easy to get player state. But I cannot figure out how to do it.

I'm creating player like this and trying to read properties (the player itself is working without problems).

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('.player_1')
player.play();
player.pause();
log(player.paused);
log(player.volume);
```

But this fails - both `paused` and `volume` are `undefined`.

I'm using latest 2.8.2 version.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/chodorowicz/wLu2v/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, John Dyer answered me on the Github support page:
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/497

It's needed to get mediaelement itself `media`

```
new MediaElementPlayer('.player_1', {success: function(media, node, player) {
  // this will be undefined since it's the player with buttons
  alert(player.paused);
  // this will be a real value since it's the underlying mediaelement
  alert(media.paused);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H7X7X/2/

​To get media element later you can use following code

```
$('player')[0].player.media;
```

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146812/make-mediaelement-same-as-html5-video