# Mediaelement.js wont play with Flash-fallback

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, mediaelement.js

I'm using Mediaelement.js to play some video and using javascript to get autoplay working. It works perfectly in Chrome, and IE10, but when it comes to Firefox and IE8 I have a problem with the flash fallback. The following works in Chrome:

```
jQuery('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();

if(autoPlay == "true") {
  player = new MediaElementPlayer("#"+currentPage+" video,audio");
  player.play();
}
```

IE8 returns the following:
[image]

And firefox returns no errors, but if I add an `alert(alert("hallo");)` in front of `player.play()`, it plays when I dismiss the alert-box.

I can't add fiddle, because of heavy use of XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah sorry, solved it a half year later:

As mentioned, the play event must be invoked in the success function

```
jQuery("video,audio").mediaelementplayer();

if(autoPlay == "1") {
  media = jQuery("#"+currentPage+" video,audio")[0];
  new MediaElement(media, {success: function(media) {
      media.play();
  }});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The player isn't loaded up and ready to play when the script presses the play button.

The script needs to press the play button inside the success function in the mediaelement instance creation.

See here:
 [How do I get mediaelement.js player state (paused, volume, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689533/how-do-i-get-mediaelement-js-player-state-paused-volume-etc/10705087)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (*webkit* specifically) may trigger the `play()` method before the *video* is completely ready and the video may just hang while loading.

I would advice to add an *event* listener to detect when the video can actually play before triggering the `play()` method like :

```
success : function (media, domObject) {
    media.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
        media.play();
    }, false);
} // success
```