# Make MediaElement same as HTML5 video

Tags: html, video, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

As is shown here:
[How do I get mediaelement.js player state (paused, volume, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689533/how-do-i-get-mediaelement-js-player-state-paused-volume-etc/10705087)

you can access MediaElement attributes by simply adding 'media' to the instance and then you can get the api described here:http://mediaelementjs.com/#api.

But how do I make it so that the 'media' wont be necessary, making the MediaElement api exactly(almost) the same as that of the html5 video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access API `methods` (as HTML5 video) but not `properties` or `events`, which still need to refer to the underlying *media* element and just after MEJS has been successfully loaded.

**Notice** that *setter* `properties` can be accessed referring either the underlying *media* element (inside the `success` setting) or the MEJS player.

So, to illustrate :

```
var myPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('.player_1', {
    success: function (mediaElement) {
        // properties need to refer the MEJS underlaying element
        console.log(mediaElement.paused); // return true
        console.log(mediaElement.muted); // returns false
        // same for events
        mediaElement.addEventListener('playing', function () {
            console.log("event triggered after play method");
        }, false);
        mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function () {
            // set time at 90 seconds and unmute if player is paused
            // but wait 3 seconds before doing that
            // notice the previous time set (145 seconds)
            setTimeout(function () {
                // setters can refer MEJS underlaying element
                mediaElement.setCurrentTime(90);
                mediaElement.setMuted(false);
            }, 3000);
        }, false);
    }
});

// methods can refer the MEJS player
myPlayer.play();

// but not properties
console.log("paused? " + myPlayer.paused); // returns undefined
console.log("muted? " + myPlayer.muted); // returns undefined

// pauses, set time and mute after 5 seconds of playing
setTimeout(function () {
    myPlayer.pause(); // method
    // setters can also refer the MEJS player
    myPlayer.setCurrentTime(145);
    myPlayer.setMuted(true);
}, 5000);
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mDW94/)**

---

**EDIT**

OP commented :

> ... could I somehow have all those elements and properties refer up by one 'element'

Interesting. Reviewing another code I wrote I think it would be possible to declare, let's call it an *`universal element`*, to which you can apply any `method`, `property` or `event`, from anywhere in your code.

The only thing you would need to do is to declare your *`one`* element as global :

```
var uElement; // the universal element
```

Then set the value withing the `success` setting to override the underlying *media* element like :

```
success: function (mediaElement) { 
    uElement = mediaElement;
    ....
}
```

From there, you could now apply any `method`, `property` or `event` to that single *`uElement`* object only. So using the previous example :

```
var uElement; // the universal element

var myPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('.player_1', {
    success: function (mediaElement) {
        // set the universal element
        uElement = mediaElement;
        // properties for universal element
        console.log(uElement.paused); // OK return true
        console.log(uElement.muted); // OK returns false
        // set events for universal element
        uElement.addEventListener('playing', function () {
            console.log("event triggered after play method");
        }, false);
        uElement.addEventListener('pause', function () {
            // set time at 90 seconds and unmute if player is paused
            // but wait 3 seconds before doing that
            // notice the previous time set (145 seconds)
            setTimeout(function () {
                // setters for universal element
                uElement.setCurrentTime(90); // OK
                uElement.setMuted(false); // OK
            }, 3000);
        }, false);
    }
});

// method for universal element
uElement.play(); // OK

// properties for universal element
console.log("paused? " + uElement.paused); // OK returns false
console.log("muted? " + uElement.muted); // OK returns false

// pauses, set time and mute after 5 seconds of playing
setTimeout(function () {
    uElement.pause(); // OK method for universal element
    // setters for universal element
    uElement.setCurrentTime(145); // OK
    uElement.setMuted(true); // OK
}, 5000);
```

See forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dCFKV/)**

**IMPORTANT**

In the example above we used `audio`, however `videos` are other type of animal.

First, you need to bear in mind that you may not able to refer to the `uElement` object, unless the video has been completely loaded AND is **ready to play**. Applying a method (like `.play()` ) to the `uElement` before the video is ready may trow a js error and malfunction.

For instance, in our previous example, if we call the `uElement.play()` method (for videos) just right after the MEJS initialization, it will trigger the js error `uElement` is *`undefined`*. This is because the method was called before the `uElement` initialization inside the `success` setting.

If we want to *autoplay* the video (`uElement.play()`) just after it's loaded (or call any other method applied to the `uElement` as a matter of fact) we need to do 2 things to workaround the situation described above:

1. add an `event` listener (inside the `success` setting) that informs us when the video is ready to play:

   ```
   uElement.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
       _canPlay = true;
   }, false);
   ```

   if the video is ready to play, then we set `true` to our flag (previously initialized as `false`)
2. validate the `_canPlay` flag inside a `setInterval()` function until is `true`, then play

   ```
   var readyToPlay = setInterval(function () {
       console.log("not ready yet");
       if ( _canPlay ) {
           console.log("Now it's ready, so play");
           uElement.play();
           clearInterval(readyToPlay);
       };
   }, 100);
   ```

This workaround can be used for youtube videos as well as self-hosted (mp4) videos.

See last **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5KQec/1/)**

**LAST NOTE** : if you have several videos and you want to apply different `methods`, `properties` or `events` to each of them, then you have to initialize them individually and create a different `uElement` for each of them

Comment: Is there any way to set this up so that the 'myPlayer' behaves the same way as a typical html5 instance? Maybe we could have some kind of a redirect within the success function?

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson : I will edit my answer (later) for a way to do that

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful discussion. I asked about the external event detection here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208232/mediaelement-detect-success-event-outside-instance-creation